# GCP windows VM will abruptly stop allowing to connect

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I have jenkins installed as a service on a Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM. 
It was working fine till a few days ago. 
Recently I am having issues connecting with the compute engine vm itself. I try to connect to that vm using a RDP and the vm would not open. I am trying to trigger jenkins using https, the requests will timeout.
I have to restart the compute engine vm itself to make it working again. It works for some minutes and starts rejecting requests again.
Weird thing is that I have jenkins slaves installed on multiple different gcp compute vms (other than the jenkins master). And while I am unable to access the VM via RDP, I can trigger jenkins requests from other gcp slaves.
I have configured SSL for the jenkins.
I have a static IP assigned to the compute vm which has jenkins server installed.

Any direction on what might be causing the gcp compute engine vm to reject connection requests would be helpful.

Comment: What size instance? Are you running low on memory or other resources? Anything in the Stackdriver logs for the instance?

Comment: Nothing in stackdriver logs. The server is at 15% memory max. Have 20 GB disk space available. It's a 16 CPU.

Comment: Not enough data in your question to figure this out. I doubt that the problem is an unstable VM instance, I would lean towards an Internet problem if you are using home based / low quality Internet. Use a tool to debug your RDP connection.